# unable to build magick for golang

Tags: go, imagemagick, magickwand

I am following this [document](https://github.com/gographics/imagick) for building the Go Imagick library.

When i ran the following command

```
go build -tags no_pkgconfig imagick
```

It throws the following exception :

```
# imagick
src/imagick/affine_matrix.go:8:29: fatal error: wand/MagickWand.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

Now to resolve that i have also installed the following packages as many people suggested to resolve the error. But it didn't work either.

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev libmagickcore-dev imagemagick
```

Moreover, when i run `go build imagick`
It throws the following error :

```
# imagick
could not determine kind of name for C.FlattenAlphaChannel
could not determine kind of name for C.RemoveAlphaChannel
```

Output of  `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand` gives the correct output

```
-fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -lMagickWand -lMagickCore
```

ImageMagick is installed to this path(/usr/include/ImageMagick) only.

Comment: This is being tracked by issue [#68](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/issues/68). Once I confirm and commit a fix, I will type up an answer explaining why this is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on [#68](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/issues/68) of the issue tracker, you are using way too old of a version of ImageMagick, which predates the versions that were tested for the master branch. Your Linux distro is older than the current available stable release.

You should manually install a newer ImageMagick, and remove the, one from apt. Or use some solution that allows you to manage multiple versions.

Answer (score 2):

Their docs [mention](https://github.com/gographics/imagick#build-tags) that `no_pkgconfig` must be used with manually set `GCO_CFLAGS` and `CGO_LDFLAGS`. So something like this should work:

```
export CGO_CFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags MagickWand)"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="$(pkg-config --libs MagickWand)"
go build -tags no_pkgconfig
```

Comment: I am still getting the error `could not determine kind of name for C.FlattenAlphaChannel
could not determine kind of name for C.RemoveAlphaChannel`

Comment: What is your OS and Go version? My solution works for your original error, but I cannot reproduce these.

Comment: ubuntu 12.04 and go1.5.2.linux-386

Comment: @Naresh Sorry, I'm on 14.04 and can't reproduce. The package maintainer has given [this example](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/issues/24#issuecomment-66534047) in the issues. If this doesn't help either you might try to raise a new issue about this.

Comment: I'm a maintainer of the imagick bindings. Please refer to the issue tracker, [#68](https://github.com/gographics/imagick/issues/68)